# Pass variable from C# - IronPython to a Python script

Tags: c#, python, .net, wpf, ironpython

I have a **WPF** application. For the purpose of this question, let's say it's a simple Window with a button. When I click on that button, I would like a **Python** script to be executed. Therefore, I went looking around and found out that I can run Python scripts using **IronPython**. *Part1* works well, it runs the python scripts. From what I've gathered from looking around the web, *Part2* is what I should do if I want to call a specific method.

```
private void btnWhatever_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    //Basic engine to run python script. - Part1
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    string pythonScriptPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));        
    ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(pythonScriptPath + "/python.py");
    ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
    source.Execute(scope); 

    //Part2
    Object myclass = engine.Operations.Invoke(scope.GetVariable("pythonScriptClass"));
    object[] parameters = new object[] { "Hi",3 };
    engine.Operations.InvokeMember(myclass, "theMethod", parameters);
}
```

The problem is, I kept getting **'Microsoft.Scripting.ArgumentTypeException'** happened in **Microsoft.Dynamic.dll : theMethod() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)**.

I understand from that error that I'm giving 3 arguments instead of 2 but I can't call a specific method another way from what I found out. I'm pretty new to IronPython and Python in general but here is a script example :

```
class pythonScriptClass:

def swapText(text, number):
    return text[number:] + text[:number]

def getLetterIndex(letter, text):
    for k in range(len(text)):
        if (letter== text[k]):
            return k
    return -1

def theMethod(text , number):
    result= swapText("textToBeSwaped", number)
    toBeReturned  = ""
    for letter in text:
        if letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            toBeReturned  = toBeReturned  + result[getLetterIndex(letter, result)]           
    return toBeReturned
```

My ultimate goal for the moment is to get this to work and therefore be able to call **theMethod()** from the Python script and get the returned value using C# - IronPython.

I have tried other methods such as : scope.SetVariable("key","value"); but I got the same error.

Comment: Know little about IronPython, but how is `object[] parameters` with `new object[] { "Hi",3 }` is interpreted in Python? It looks 2-length but treated as 3-length, possibly "H", "i" and "3"? What happens with `{"foo", 3}`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @dytori . To answer your question, it does the same thing with "foo".

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked you were using a class signature. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for python member method, the first argument is `self`.

```
class pythonScriptClass:
  def theMethod(self, text, number):
    # and call self.swapText(...)
```

This is why the number of arguments went wrong.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you ! I'll have to go check more about those member / non-member methods...

Comment: Member method may not be a proper term... Please check instance / class / static method in Python.